# unable to render carrierwave file validation message in modal popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created modal popup for post model which has text, filename fields. I'm opening post new form from index through modal popup. whenever I submit without filling data then it is showing the validation messages for both fields. But when I choose other than pdf file and entered any text in 'text' field then click on save.

1. Invalid file validation is not showing
2. once object got save not redirecting to index page.

   form_for @post, html: { multipart: true, class: 'json' }, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do

Used gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'

```
if @post.save
  render json: { render_layout: render_to_string('index.html', layout: false, formats: :html) }

    else
      render json: {
        render_layout: render_to_string('new', layout: false), success: false
      }
    end
```